# Using regex in NotePad++ to find multiple keywords?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Does anyone know how to use regex to find lines that have any of the keywords I list?

I'm trying to bookmark all lines that contain at least one of the keywords from my list, the lines don't need to have all of them.

For example, if a line has any of these keywords, I want it bookmarked:  keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4, keyword5

Comment: don't use notepad++, but you could try `kw1|kw2|kw3|kwn`

Answer (score 3):

You can match different keywords with `|` like so: `keyword1|keyword2|keyword3`. That regex would match any of keyword1, keyword2 and keyword3.